# Maven build error - SAP WebIDE MTA Application

Tags: maven, sap-web-ide

I'm developing a MTA Application in the SAP WebIDE with two modules. One html5 Module and one Java Module (candidatereportmail). The html5 Module gets build fine, but when it gets to the Java module there are the following errors since about 4 weeks. I haven't changed anything in the Java module, so I'm pretty confused on why there are suddenly these errors.

The pom.xml definetly looks fine, and worked fine till now, so I'm suspecting that maybe some libaries used for building might not exist anymore? But wouldn't I then get different error messages?

Has anyone ever experienced anything similiar? Would really appreciate some hints on what could possible cause the problem.

```
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) on project candidatereportmail: Error assembling WAR: /projects/candidatereport-1/candidatereportmail/pom.xml isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] 
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] 
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
10:47:36 (Executor) [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
10:47:36 (Executor) [2021-04-15 08:47:36] ERROR could not build the "candidatereportmail" module: could not execute the "mvn clean package" command: exit status 1
10:47:36 (Executor) make: *** [Makefile_20210415084718.mta:37: candidatereportmail] Error 1
10:47:36 (Executor) Error: could not build the MTA project: could not execute the "make -f Makefile_20210415084718.mta p=cf mtar= strict=true mode=" command: exit status 2
10:47:36 (MTA BUILD) The "Task for mta build" process finished with code 1
10:47:36 (MTA BUILD) Build of "candidatereport-1" failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

So the following two properties in the  section of my pom.xml resulted in the error while building the Java Module:

```
<directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
```

It seems like it is not possible to build the application war in the root directory, so had to add an /target (or some other folder) and it finally worked.

```
<directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
```

Still strange, since it worked till about two weeks ago...